# Responsive CSS content without media queries

Tags: css, iphone, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

Ok, so i'm working on my [website](http://www.demihokin.com), I am trying to make it responsive but without the use of any frameworks or @media queries in the css. I have used relative lengths such as %, vw, and vh on widths, heights, and fonts in the CSS. I thought this was working ok when i uploaded my [website](http://www.demihokin.com). When i re-size the browser window it does kind of work (minus the padding and margin issues). I thought my idea had worked until i checked my site on a iphone 6s and tablet. iPhone and tablet seem ok when in portrait but when in landscape its really bad! The idea i am going for, is that all content to resize/scaled down and remain within the yellow border that is attached around the body. Is it possible for me to do this without using media queries? How do i make my content properly scale down with the Viewport?

## HTML & CSS

```css
html{
 overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #ffff00; 
}

body::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}

p a {
 color: #ffff00;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
}


video{
 position: fixed;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 z-index: -1;
}

.screen {
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 background: grey;
 opacity: 0.4;

}

.container{
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 50px;
 margin: 0px auto; 
 min-width: 60%;

}

.menu{
 height: 50%;
 width:50%;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
}

.logo{
 display: inline-block;
 max-height: 25vh; 
 max-width:  25vw;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.logo h1{
 font-size: 3vw;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.nav-menu{
 margin: 20px auto;
 font-size: 2vw;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 13px 2px 1px 2px;
 border: 3px solid #ffff00;
 line-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,Chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <!-- SEO META -->
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, Meta Tags, Metadata" />
  <meta name="description" content="WEBSITE">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
    <title>| Louis Lombardi |</title>

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
              <!-- video -->
               <video id='video' preload>   
                  <source  src="vid/vt1.mp4" type="video/mp4" > 
                    <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</p> 
               </video> 
<!-- MENU SECTION --> 
      <div class="container">
        <div class="menu col-12">
            <div class="logo"> <img src="img/louis-media-logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="media and design logo"> <h1>MEDIA</h1> </div>
            <div class="clear-fix"></div>
             <div class="nav-menu"> <p> <a href="#">ABOUT</a> </p> </div>
              <div class="clear-fix"></div>
                <div class="nav-menu"> <p> <a href="#">PORJECTS</a> </p> </div>
                  <div class="clear-fix"></div>
                   <div class="nav-menu"> <p> <a href="#">CONTACT</a> </p> </div>
        </div> 
    </div> <!-- Container --> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I think `vh` and `vw` units are backwards when in iOS landscape. If you look at the [Known Issues](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) you might get some more info. I think `vh` takes into account the bottom bar in Safari, as well. See this for some potential workarounds: https://gist.github.com/pburtchaell/e702f441ba9b3f76f587

Comment: Thanks for the links, they're really helpful. It looks like i will have to use media queries in the CSS to achieve what i want. I think i am almost there just having trouble with with iPhone in landscape.